# Any idea to improve the design?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, layout, user-experience

Hi I'm working on a web app, I'm currently try to make the profile info page, but I'm stuck because I'm not a good designer so I don't know how to improve the page to get it better... this is the screen, anyone can tell me what to change to improve the appearance??

[image]

Even I dont know how to improve the navigation bar(Account,Billing,Requests) over the card.

Thanks if anyone can tell me how to improve the looking!!

Comment: use a css library if you aren't using one, Use templates from that library, for example you don't want a toggler on a laptop or PC, use full size Navbar, also take a look at snippets provided by some websites like [here](https://freefrontend.com/) , [here](https://www.littlesnippets.net/) or [here](https://bootsnipp.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a design team, stick to an UI framework to make your life easier!

I assume that you are using React for building this web app, here is my suggestion for common UI frameworks:

1. [Ant Design](https://ant.design/) (recommend for large community support)
2. [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/) (recommend for large community support)
3. [reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/)

If you want to improve your UX design, I recommend this book for non-design background developer:

[The Non-Designer's Design Book by Robin Williams](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00125MJYM)